# Is a flat morphism of complex algebraic varieties open in the analytic topology?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, analytic-geometry

Let $X,Y$ be algebraic varieties over $\mathbb{C}$. A morphism $f:X\to Y$ induces a morphism $f^{an}:X^{an}\to Y^{an}$ between the associated complex analytic spaces (actually, I am interested only in the topological aspects). There are a lot of results relating the properties of $X,Y,f$  and those of $X^{an},Y^{an},f^{an}$, known collectively as GAGA. I am interested in the following:

> If $f$ is flat, does it follow that $f^{an}$ is open?

It is known that if $f$ if flat then it is open in the Zariski topology. A similar looking "dual" statement that I am aware of is that if $f$ is proper, then $f^{an}$ is proper in the topological sense and in particular closed.

In general, I would like to know sufficient conditions on $f$, for $f^{an}$ to be open.

#### Edit:

This is not stated or proved in Serre's GAGA (at least not explicitly). I did read somewhere that it is true, but without a proof or reference to one.

Comment: @QiL'8, great! thanks. The Moret-Bailly paper gives "f is universally open if and only if the induced map is open in the analytic topology". This settles the question, since flat morphism of finite type is universally open. Perhaps you can post the link as an answer, so I can accept it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is yes. See [this post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/41158/are-flat-morphisms-of-analytic-spaces-open) from mathoverflow.

Blablablabla.....

Comment: The stupid line "blabla..." is to prevent Stackexchange to convert this "answer" back a comment.